# datagridview change row color, when date expired or less

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, datagridview, colors

My code works for changing color in rows, but I need to make correct if statement. In cell[0] I have date value "2013.03.20". This date means product expired date.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  if (row.Cells[0](dont know how write))
  {
   row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
  }
}
```

Example:

- Today is 2013.03.10
- Product expired date is 2013.03.20.
- Last 7 days of product expiry will give Yellow color. (i.e. from 13th till 20th)
- When product is expired, I want to show it as Red.

Comment: What is the name of the DataField.. you can do it using Index or by field name.. I personally would do it by fieldname that way if the data structure changes you don't have to worry about updating the FiledName Index values throughout the code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Simon said you should also handle incorrect date format for DateTime.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var expirationDate =  DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            var sevenDayBefore = expirationDate.AddDays(-7);

            if (now > sevenDayBefore && now < expirationDate)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (now > expirationDate)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Used your variant :) Thx for you all help. Your code will be stored in my brains :)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this (off the top of my head with no Visual Studio so forgive any minor syntax errors). You would probably need to be a bit more robust with the DateTime conversion to handle nulls, invalid dates etc. You can tweak the conditions to match your exact requirements:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                switch (Convert.ToDatetime(row.Cells[0].ToString()))
                {
                   case > DateTime.Today:
                      row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SomeColor;  
                      break;
                   case == DateTime.Today:
                      row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SomeColor;  
                      break;
                    case else:
                      row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SomeColor;  
                      break;
                }
```

Comment: Exactly the style of response that I would post! + 1

Comment: I write my conditions UP. If today date has left 7 days then yellow, when today is bigger then expired date then red.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **RowDataBound** event handler instead of using foreach. I think using RowDataBound event handler is for those things.

```
public void dataGridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Product currentProduct = e.Item.DataItem as Product;

        TimeSpan diffDate = DateTime.Now - currentProduct.ExpireDate;

        if (dateDiff < TimeSpan.FromDays(0))
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else if (dateDiff < TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example.

```
DateTime currentToday = (DateTime)this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Date"].Value;

if (currentToday <= DateTime.Now.Date)
{
      e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red; //Font Color
      e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red; //Selection Font color
}
```